# How to retrieve a url attribute with Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Within this page - https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download I am trying to retrieve a link - https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/esp32-s2-mini/ToolFlasher/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-3.0-x64.exe . This link is wrapped in a meta tag within a noscript tag and has url as its attribute. I can't seem to scrape that link.

Here is my code

```
download_url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download'

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless') 
service_obj = Service('chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=op)
driver.get(download_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//* [@id="cmpwelcomebtnyes"]/a'))).click()
z = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "meta")
for i in z:
   print(i.get_attribute('url'))
driver.quit()
```

Each iteration returns "None", any suggestions?

[Picture of the link within the inspect elements tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKO6F.png)

Comment: hmm, I don't see that link anywhere in the page

Comment: within that page, which is - 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download' press inspect, and then ctrl + f within  https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/esp32-s2-mini/ToolFlasher/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-3.0-x64.exe and it should be there. Also, once the download stops, the link disappears, so you sort of have to do it fast. Also, I edited the post with a picture of the link within the inspect elements tab

Comment: after download I am redirected to another page, how did you avoid that?

Comment: Link is not there.

Comment: I don't avoid it, you have to make it in 5-10 seconds lol

Comment: Hello, yes it did! sorry for the delay, forgot you have to mark it down as solved, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, You want to get the URL

[image]

in your [`page`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download). Just to get the URL you can either use string manipulation methods or you will have to use regex to parse the string.

Here is how you can do it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
import re

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download'
driver.get(url)

jscode = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//noscript").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(re.search(r'url=(.*)\?', jscode).group(1))
```

which gives us the output :

```
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe
```